# Is there a way to conditionally add expiration policies to an S3 bucket in cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I'm defining an S3 bucket in a CloufFormation template:

```
Resources:
  Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      AccessControl: Private
      BucketName: !Ref BucketName
```

I want to **optionally** add a retention policy to the bucket, so:

```
Resources:
  Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      AccessControl: Private
      BucketName: !Ref BucketName
      LifecycleConfiguration:
        Rules:
          - ExpirationInDays: !Ref RetentionDays
```

I don't need the LifecycleConfiguration/ExpirationInDays on all deployments of the CF template because some buckets will retain their objects indefinitely. I've [looked at the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket-lifecycleconfig-rule.html#cfn-s3-bucket-lifecycleconfig-rule-expirationindays), and there doesn't appear to be a value for retain indefinitely/don't expire.
I'd thought about having two buckets - one with the LifecycleConfiguration, and one without, and then I could use a condition (e.g. if the RetentionDays parameter = -1) to determine which bucket gets created:

```
Conditions:
  HasNoRetention: !Equals [!Ref RetentionDays, -1]
  HasRetention: !Not [Condition: HasNoRetention]
Resources:
  Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Condition: HasNoRetention
    Properties:
      AccessControl: Private
      BucketName: !Ref BucketName
  BucketWithRetention:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Condition: HasRetention
    Properties:
      AccessControl: Private
      BucketName: !Ref BucketName
      LifecycleConfiguration:
        Rules:
          - ExpirationInDays: !Ref RetentionDays
```

The issue here is that the buckets have different names in the YAML definition ("Bucket", and "BucketWithRetention") - so it would be difficult to !Ref the correct bucket in other resources later on as you'd have to determine which bucket was created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following should work using [Fn::If](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html#intrinsic-function-reference-conditions-if):

```
LifecycleConfiguration:
  Rules:
    !If 
      - RetentionDays
      - - ExpirationInDays: !Ref RetentionDays
      - !Ref 'No::Value'
```

Comment: Accepted. Just found the documentation for it deeper into the Conditionals documentation on AWS (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html#w2ab1c21c24c21c39b8c10).

Answer (score 3):

I was able to make LifecycleConfiguration conditional. It worked for me like this:

```
 LifecycleConfiguration:
   Fn::If:
     - HasRetention
     - Rules:
         - ExpirationInDays: !Ref RetentionDays
           Status: Enabled
     - Ref: AWS::NoValue
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `AWS::NoValue`, you can also include rules for `NonProd` retention days if you're dealing with `Prod` and `NonProd` environments

```
 LifecycleConfiguration:
   Fn::If:
     - HasRetention
     - Rules:
         - ExpirationInDays: !Ref RetentionDays
           Status: Enabled
     - Rules:
         - ExpriationInDays: !Ref NonProdRententionDays
           Status: Enabled
```